# Is it possible to avoid long distance charges with an IP-based phone?

Tags: voip, pbx

Is it possible to avoid long distance charges with an IP-based phone? I am not talking about client-based VOIP services here (like Skype), I am talking about a REAL IP phone using Asterisk or some other PBX software to provide land line-to-land line connections. I assume it must be impossible, because at some point there will carrier charges, but thought I would check anyway.

If you don't know what a PBX is or do not have a thorough understanding of telephony, please do not answer.

Comment: No;  It is not...

Comment: You will pay whatever charges your provider (voice or VoIP) sets for the calls you make according to whatever price plan you have with them (just like any other telephone service). Just because your handset is a VoIP handset makes no difference.

Comment: Some VoIP providers provide special rates of course. Some even provide free calls when both caller and recipient are using the same VoIP service. A VoIP company I used to work for did exactly that.